# CPU upgrade failed on a Dell Precision Tower

Tags: memory, cpu, dell-precision

Just got two new Xeon Gold 6240 CPUs for a Dell Precision 7920 Tower. Dell's website says these chips are compatible with this computer. After installing the new chips, I'm getting a pre-boot failure with the blinking light code for "Memory/RAM Failure". Reverting to the old CPUs fixes the problem, so I really don't think the problem is with the RAM. Is it possible that the old RAM is not compatible with the new CPUs? What other problems could throw this error? Thanks.

Comment: You sure the cpu's are good?

Comment: They're brand new, and I tested each one independently. I guess they both could be bad, but I think it's unlikely.

Comment: Is the BIOS up to date?

Comment: " Is it possible that the old RAM is not compatible with the new CPUs?" - No;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bios has had 16 revisions since initial release, [version 2.0.4](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=xc4tn&oscode=w764&productcode=precision-7920-workstation) added support for newer processors, check to see what version is installed, if lower than 2.0.4, update the bios to at least 2.0.4

[Your support page](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/precision-7920-workstation/drivers)

Comment: This. Updated the BIOS and it worked like a charm. Thanks Moab.

Comment: Even a blind pig finds and acorn every once in a while, I got lucky, you are welcome.